# Firebase Crash not linked

Tags: android, firebase

have a project that needs to use xmlns:tools, in this case:

```
<uses-sdk
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="24"
    tools:overrideLibrary="io.huq.sourcekit" />
```

But Firebase does not work when I use this.

It gives me this error:

```
com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
```

Comment: please share your dependencies from build.gradle file

Comment: please share more logs and gradle code.

Comment: This is not an error. If you want to use Fireabse Auth or Firebase Crash reporting add them to your dependencies. Otherwise they won't be linked... because they're not there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I saw my gradle and I realized that I forgot to put the compile of the firebase crash:

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'


   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
}
```

I added:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0'
```

And work.

Comment: This is deprectated, should use https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started#android

Comment: As @DanielGomezRico said you method is no more working. Configure the project according to the official docs